# Stateless library: change state after action with parameters

Tags: c#, parameter-passing, stateless

In the [stateless](https://github.com/dotnet-state-machine/stateless) library it is possible to have triggers with parameters. I have a simple state machine and I want that the user can run a method with parameters and this method shall execute a trigger with parameters and then change state. How can I do this? Example:

```cs
public MyMachine {
  public enum MyStates {
    StateOne,
    StateTwo
  }
  
  public enum MyTriggers {
    FirstTrigger,
    SecondTrigger
  }

  public int MyNumber {get; private set;}
  private readonly StateMachine<MyStates, MyTriggers> _stateMachine;

  public MyMachine(){
    _stateMachine = new StateMachine<MyStates, MyTriggers>(MyStates.StateOne);

    var myFirstTrigger = machine.SetTriggerParameters<int>(MyTriggers.FirstTrigger);

    _stateMachine.Configure(MyStates.StateOne)
      .InternalTransition<int>(myFirstTrigger, (value, t) => OnSetMyNumber(value))
      .Permit(MyTriggers.FirstTrigger, MyStates.StateTwo);
  }

  void OnSetMyNumber(int value) => MyNumber = value;

  public void SetNumber(int value) => machine.Fire(myFirstTrigger, value);
}
```

Then calling it:

```cs
var machine = MyMachine();
machine.SetNumber(10);
```

Throws the following exception:

```cs
System.InvalidOperationException: "Multiple permitted exit transitions are configured from state 'InitialState' for trigger 'CreateInitialPlan'. Guard clauses must be mutually exclusive."
```

This is because of the `.Permit(MyTriggers.FirstTrigger, MyStates.StateTwo)`. If I delete this line, though, it does not change to state "StateTwo". What am I missing?

**Expected behaviour**
I want to call `SetNumber(10)` and then the state machine should change to state "StateTwo".

Answer (score 0):

```
_stateMachine.Configure(MyStates.StateOne)
  .InternalTransition<int>(myFirstTrigger, (value, t) => OnSetMyNumber(value))
  .Permit(MyTriggers.FirstTrigger, MyStates.StateTwo);
```

You have two transitions out of `StateOne` defined for `FirstTrigger`, but neither of them has a guard condition.  So, when `FirstTrigger` occurs, how is the state machine supposed to decide which transition to take?

If you delete `.Permit(MyTriggers.FirstTrigger, MyStates.StateTwo)`, of course it won't transition to `StateTwo`, because you no longer have a transition from `StateOne` to `StateTwo` defined.

Without knowing what the rest of your application looks like, maybe try this:  Add a trigger specifically for `SetNumber`.  Define it as an `InternalTransition` on `StateOne`.  Then, you can set that number as often as you like - assuming you're in `StateOne` - and you can transition to `StateTwo` via `FirstTrigger`.  Or, if you always want to move to `StateTwo` when the number is set (`FirstTrigger` occurs), just remove the internal transition back to `StateOne` and move the `OnSetMyNumber` call to the transition to `StateTwo`.

As it is, you're telling the state machine you want to both transition from `StateOne` to `StateTwo` *and* also remain in `StateOne`.  Those both can't happen at the same time.